# Load data from txt to JTable. Without Vectors or Buffreader

Tags: jtable, save

I create the table in this way:

```
    static JTable table;

public table(){
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    String [] columns ={ "Name","Surname","Phone"};

    Object[][]data={
            {"-","-","-",},
            {"Bob","ZYX","606129212"},
    };
    table=new JTable(data,columns);
```

Write to txt file this way:

```
try{
             PrintWriter pclose = new PrintWriter("data.txt");
                for(int i=0;i<table.getRowCount();i++){
                    for(int j=0;j<table.getColumnCount();j++){
                        pclose.println(table.getValueAt(i,j));

                    }
                }

                pclose.flush();
                pclose.close();


                }catch(FileNotFoundException e1){
                    System.out.println("End of the file");

                }

        }
```

In txt it looks like:

```
-
-
-
Bob
ZYX
606129212
```

Now I want as simply as it is possible to read frome the txt to JTable back.
Without using Vectors or BuffReader(will be good for me if I will use Scanner).
Do you have any tips?

Comment: Example code if will you need it later:File file = new File("name of file.txt");
       
             try { 
              Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file); 
                 for (int i = 0;i<table.getRowCount(); i++) { 
                  for(int j=0;j<table.getColumnCount();j++) { 
                         String h = scanner.nextLine(); 
                         table.setValueAt(h, i, j);
                     } 
                 } 
                 scanner.close(); 
             
    }catch(FileNotFoundException e1){
     System.out.println("File not found");
     
    }